# Arrays with 2 string parts Java

Tags: java, arrays

since ive got problem with my homework i would like to ask you 
im re-programming this "word guessing game" and i have problem with arrays.
The original code

```
private SearchedWord word;

public WordGiver() {
    word = new SearchedWord("Camel", "Desert Animal");
}
```

Camel guessed word 
,Desert Animal Advice

```
private String[] SearchedWord1;


public String SearchedWord2(String word) {
    SearchedWord = new String[19];
    SearchedWord[0] = ("Camel", "Desert Animal");
}
```

That part with Desert Animal it says ) expected.
Can you help me with that ?

Comment: That is invalid syntax, what are you trying to do on that line?

Comment: You have a array of String and you are trying to put ("Camel","Desert Animal"); into it, but it's not the String ;) so to do first ;)

Comment: `Searchword` is an array of strings so `Searchword[0]` is the first string in that array. It can only contain 1 string not 2 of them. Is there a reason why you would put 2 strings in there??

Comment: 1)Well im trying from orginal code make array and i have no clue what to do with that
2) It is a advice for that game like you are guessing words like camel.
And you need advice to guess that word

Answer (score 1):

```
SearchedWord = new String[]{"Camel","Desert Animal"};
```

You will have SearchedWord array with two elements Camel and Desert Animal.

Comment: you are welcome :)